# How to Import Data to MongoDB.Atlas on Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb-atlas

I need to import 500K+ small records into a MongoDB Atlas collection. I've no access to linux/mac machines and need to do it on Windows 10.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The `mongoimport` utility works well on Windows. It can be installed with the [Community Edition MSI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/).

You can import from EJSON, CSV or TSV, depending on your needs. Take a look at the official docs for [working examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/).

If you have trouble post-install, share a sample source record for additional pointers.